# The .reset() method of common smart pointers

Tags: c++

It seems to me that the reset method in the boost scoped_ptr and shared_ptr lead to incorrect order of construction and destruction:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<Component> component(GetDefaultComponent());
component.reset(new BetterComponent); // 1. Creation of the new object
                                      // 2. Destruction of the old object
```

This is the wrong order IMO.

It is possible to first call the reset method without arguments and then set the new pointer. However that seems like a workaround to me. (And it being a "workaround" implies that there is something wrong.)

I am convinced that the boost people are very smart. So there must have been a rationale for the current approach.

Does anyone know more?

Comment: "This is the wrong order IMO." Why is this your opinion?

Comment: Because the overlap in existance can cause problems at application level code. Especially if each object performs some form of registration/unregisration on creation/destruction. I have acutally spend time debugging issues like this. The workaround eventually being calling reset() before reset(new X).

Comment: However I can see that from the perspective of the boost people the situation is different. Keeping things consistent at the boost level is their responsibility, not application level code.

I think this is analoguous with how kernel developers look at the system differently than their users do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/12/10163578.aspx

Comment: I use objects that perform registration/unregistration on creation/destruction and completely don't see how this can cause a problem. It won't cause the objects to register as alive when they're not or unregister themselves when they're alive.

Answer (score 13):

It's absolutely the right order. What happens if `new BetterComponent` throws? Whoops. This is the same order in which everything happens, it's known as copy-and-swap, and it's the best way to go.

Especially since you didn't actually give any reason that the current order is wrong.

Comment: +1.  Exactly.  Constructors can throw exceptions, destructors cannot.  (Well, _should_ not.)  Ergo this is exactly the right order.

Answer (score 1):

You can always refactor this in a free function (and do beware of the exception-safety consequences):

```
template<typename T, typename Pointer, typename... U>
void
emplace_reset(Pointer& pointer, U&&... u)
{
    pointer.reset();
    pointer.reset(new T(std::forward<U>(u)...));
}
// use as: emplace_reset<BetterComponent>(component);
```

But this is *not* a workaround because the reset member does just as advertised. What you're asking for is a new functionality.

A possible rationale for not providing the functionality you want (beyond exception-safety/transactional semantics) is that pointers have never, ever created the objects they point to: the constructors assume ownership but that's it. `reset` is consistent in that manner.

Comment: +1 Leaving the SmarPtr in charge of the actual creation of the object is a good thing IMO. Because then creation, ownership and destruction all belong to one and the same object. I believe this makes the code less error prone and easier to understand.

Comment: @StackedCrooked I favor the use of 'factories' like `make_shared`. And still, if you were to write a smart pointer that took care of creation, you would still have to carefully separate the `reset`-like member from the `emplace_reset`-like member due to the very, very different exception-safety guarantees.